# C# Newtonsoft json serialization Dictionary<int, int> get saved as <string, int>

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to load some saved json string and turn it into a <int, int> dictionary, then add some items and then turn it back into a string. But for some reason the key gets saved as a string, not int.

I'm using the following code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, int>>("{}");
dictionary[1] = 1;
string updatedDictionary = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary);
Debug.Log(updatedDictionary); // {"1":1}
Debug.Log(updatedDictionary[1]); // "
```

but the updatedDictionary is printed as `{"1":1}`... why is that? And how can I fix this? I cannot event just convert to string when looking up the dictionary because it only allows int look ups. So I really need to make sure that the json is saved as int int key value pair, and not turn into string keys.

The same happens when I do `dictionary.Add(1, 1)` So I'm pretty sure the problem lies in the SerializeObject call.

Comment: Did you try to deserialize _updatedictionary_? What if _dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, int>>(updatedDictionary);_?

Comment: There's nothing to fix. Not quoting them would be nonconformant.

Comment: Could you please clarify how you expect resulting **JSON** file to look like?

Comment: @madreflection, right, so Dictionary<int, int> would never be json compatible?

Comment: It's perfectly compatible. `JsonConvert` will translate the keys back to int when you're deserializing to `Dictionary<int,int>`. Just don't expect to get `{1:1}` in serialized form. That's not proper JSON. `{"1":1}` is.

Comment: @madreflection well that's strange because it does not print `1` when I do `Debug.Log(updatedDictionary[1])` it print `"`

Comment: `Debug.Log` is logging characters from `updatedDictionary`, which is a string containing `{"1":1}`. It has `[0] == '{'`, `[1] == '"'`, and so on. Deserialize that back to `Dictionary<int, int>` and *that* will have a key of `1` with a value of `1`, both ints.

Comment: Oh god. it's late, it Saturday. and slightly embarrassing. Thanks for 2nd pair of eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Json Object must use strings for their keys.

[https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp#:~:text=Object%20Syntax&text=JSON%20objects%20are%20written%20in,are%20separated%20by%20a%20colon](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp#:%7E:text=Object%20Syntax&text=JSON%20objects%20are%20written%20in,are%20separated%20by%20a%20colon).

Comment: Thanks. I get it. I was playing around in jsoneditoronline.org which for some reason supports integer json keys.